# How to pin commit in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I've run into an issue with Jenkins where different stages run on different commits. We have a cron job that runs tests in parallel and then builds an image once the tests are done. What happens is:

1. The job starts running the tests against commit A
2. While the tests are running, someone merges commit B into master
3. The build image stage starts against commit B, which is not the same commit that had the test run.

I would like to stop this from happening and ensure that all stages run on commit A. Is there a simple way to do this?

What I've come up with is creating a separate job that tags the latest commit in master as a release candidate and modifying the build job to run against the tag, but this is sloppy and creates an extra dependency.

Comment: Please include your Jenkinsfile code and your pipeline settings description into the question. Without that information it's impossible to answer it.

Comment: If the completion of step 1 triggers step 3, then pass commit `A` on over. Step 3 should use the received commit ID instead of `master`.

Comment: I believe the common practice is to tag at the beginning of the job and reference it throughout. So you have the right idea. I'm just missing why you need a separate job to do it.